# How to play video on iOS that's loaded manually from a socket?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation, rtsp

Rather tricky one this...

I'm trying to stream a video (H264) across a network on iOS. However, I'm getting the video data into a buffer through an open socket to the remote server (using CocoaAsyncSocket), so I don't have a URL to the video that I can use to create an AVAsset or an MPMoviePlayer. The video is a live stream, so the data will just keep coming (i.e. No set duration) if that makes any difference.

I'm having to do it this way as the server is an RTSP server. I've written my own RTSP client for the sending of commands and receiving of responses, and now I'm trying to do something useful with the video data that comes over the connection.

Any ideas on how I can play back this video?  The only things I can think of currently are somehow saving to a file and loading that (but I don't see how that'll work, as I'll be continually loading new data), or resorting to doing it manually somehow with something like ffmpeg. And no, unfortunately I can't make the server do HTTP Live Streaming instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, I'm currently wondering if I can perhaps implement my own NSURLProtocol that serves up the video data that I buffer from the RTSP server. I might then be able to create an AVAsset with a URL of that type?

Comment: Also, maybe you could fake an HTTP live stream by creating a local .M3U8 and segmenting the stream on the local filesystem. While it sounds a little hackish, it might work...

Comment: I'm also wondering how to play back this type of stream.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this to work?

Comment: For reference: in the end, we wound up having to write our own video decoder using the ffmpeg libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to dig this deeply into AVFoundation yet, but you might be able to pull it off by creating an `AVAsset` with an `AVAssetWriter`. You provide `AVAssetWriter` an instance of `AVAssetWriterInput` which takes `CMSampleBuffer` data and packages it up for the `AVAssetWriter`.

Based on the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriterInput_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `AVAssetWriterInput`, it is designed to take data from a "real-time source".

I wish I could be of more help, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the help - AVAssetWriterInput does look promising! However, I can't see that there's any way to create an AVAsset with an AVAssetWriter. AVAssert requires a URL (remote or a file) to load, and AVAssetWriter can produce a file at a given URL - however, presumably I shouldn't (or maybe even can't?) load a file into an AVAsset that's still being written to. And it'll constantly be being written to because it's a live stream.